# Can't import Aer from Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

When running the following code:

```python
from qiskit import Aer
```

I encountered the following error:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit import Aer

ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'
```

Why is that the case?